# Configuration options for xConnect when installing Sitecore 10 XP1 using Sitecore Installation Framework (SIF)

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-install-framework, installation

My question is related to the configuration of SIF installation scripts for the xConnect component.

There are some options within the example XP1 topology scripts for which I need some additional guidance beyond what is included in the parameter descriptions within the JSON files.

In the following file:

- xconnect-xp1-collection.json

I need to understand what options are available for:

- XConnectEnvironment
- XConnectLogLevel

**Does anyone know where these settings are documented?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XConnectEnvironment` ( Content copied from: http://thebitsthatbyte.com/sitecore-9-feature-xconnect-configuration-environment-xconnectenvironment-sif-parameter/ ) It actually unlocks a powerful feature of Sitecore 9 where you are able to set the configuration environment of xConnect allowing you to leverage different configurations for differing environments/development and testing scenarios.

For `XConnectLogLevel` you can use (values from https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics):

- **Verbose**   Verbose is the noisiest level, rarely (if ever) enabled for a production app.
- **Debug** Debug is used for internal system events that are not necessarily observable from the outside, but useful when determining how something happened.
- **Information**   Information events describe things happening in the system that correspond to its responsibilities and functions. Generally these are the observable **actions** the system can perform.
- **Warning**   When service is degraded, endangered, or may be behaving outside of its expected parameters, Warning level events are used.
- **Error** When functionality is unavailable or expectations broken, an Error event is used.
- **Fatal** The most critical level, Fatal events demand immediate attention.

Comment: Thanks Marek, this is very helpful!